# Storing time varying graphs in a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-design, time-series

I have a graph like this:

```
Source | Sink | Timestamp
A        B      2012-08-01 03:02:00
B        C      2012-08-01 03:02:00
C        D      2012-08-01 03:02:00
...
```

I am constructing this table from another table. I would like to design my table so that:

- It uses the minimum storage without comprising on being able to get the most recent graph (I don't care about previous graphs for a real-time scenario)
- It should be possible to study the graph evolution (how fast is something changing etc.)

Currently, other than storing `Source`, `Sink` and a `Timestamp`, there are no other optimizations. Considering that every snapshot contains 800K links, storing the graph in its entirety is not possible so I am looking for possible `delta` based approaches. Any suggestions on how to approach this problem?

The graph itself is highly dynamic i.e. nodes and links can be added or removed at each snapshot.

Comment: What kind of information is associated to graph nodes and does it evolve over time? In other words, do you just add/remove nodes, or you can also modify them?

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic: At least for now, there is no modification of nodes involved but nodes and links can be added or removed during each snapshot.

Comment: Have you considered triggers yet?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking at something like this:

[image]

SNAPSHOT_VER ("version") is monotonically incremented with each new snapshot. Each new snapshot is a delta that adds or removes nodes and edges relative to the previous snapshot:

- When adding new nodes/edges, you simply create a new SNAPSHOT and use its SNAPSHOT_VER for NODE.CREATED_VER and EDGE.CREATED_VER. Leave DELETED_VER at NULL for now.
- When deleting the nodes/edges, simply set the DELETED_VER according to the snapshot at which they were deleted.

When querying for the graph as it existed at the given snapshot, you should be able to do it similar to this:

```
SELECT *
FROM NODE
WHERE
    CREATED_VER <= @snapshot_ver
    AND (DELETED_VER IS NULL OR @snapshot_ver < DELETED_VER)
```

*(Equivalent query can be constructed for EDGE.)*

This will get all the nodes that were created at the given snapshot or earlier, and were either not deleted at all or were deleted later than the given snapshot.

When querying for the latest graph, you can simply:

```
SELECT *
FROM NODE
WHERE DELETED_VER IS NULL
```

You'll probably need a composite index on {DELETED_VER, CREATED_VER DESC} (in both NODE and EDGE) for good performance in both of these cases.